# how to use background broadcast receiver with the android map view annotation update every time

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview

I am using background map service for my application for updating the android map view every time. So annotation needs to be updated, there is a problem when I update the map view, it freezes and is too slow. Can any one help?

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            // intent can contain any data
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post more code and explain more? Can you finally get the update data even if it is slow?

Comment: @bjiang in our application,background map refresh using broadcast receiver if new user has been comes into the application that user need to show in the annotation in map that is the problem,i can able to show the new user but my app slow and freeze any solution

Comment: Due to your description, I think it's not a problem on your `broadcastReceiver`, it seems that the map cannot get the data from your new user or something.

Comment: @bjiang with out map refresh add new marker from web service how it will possible